# Windows Boot Manager Black Screen in dual Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

I installed windows 10 on 2 partitions of the same disk.
The Windows Boot Manager has a black screen, so I cannot see anything, only the mouse cursor.
It can be interacted with (if I press down+Enter I get to the second installation, if the 30 secs pass automatically goes to the default one).

Not sure why this is happening.
The machine is a Razer Blade Advanced 15 2021.

Comment: How have you installed the second Windows? A recent computer uses surely UEFI, so the multi-boot should not be managed at all by the Windows bootmanager.

Comment: Used a normal usb with the windows ISO on it, and normal install.
Funny thing is it works when installing, but looks like when all drivers are updated in the second partition it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it.
Leaving this if someone in the future has the same issue:

I had to update the intel drivers from the intel page.
Windows was stating that it had the latest ones, but that was not the case.
It looks like that the windows 10 install had a basic ones that worked, but when auto updated by Windows Update, the ones that were installed did not.